# How do I set state on a map value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-state

**Here, I want to be able to set the product.quantity with setCount.**

```
  let [product.quantity, setCount] = useState(product.quantity);
```

**set increment/decrement for product.quantity**

```
 const incrementCount = () => {
  setCount(product.quantity + 1);
};

const decrementCount = () => {
    setCount(product.quantity -1);
};
  
return (
        {
```

**mapping starts**

```
cart.map((product)=> (
<>
   <Product>
```

**Decrement/Increment on click**

```
<button onClick={incrementCount}>+</button>    
  <button onClick={decrementCount}>-</button>
  
</div>
  <ProductAmountContainer>
```

**How can I pass this value product.quantity to useState?**

```
<ProductAmount>  {product.quantity} </ProductAmount>
   </ProductAmountContainer>
   <ProductPrice>$ {product.price}</ProductPrice>
   </Product>
   </>
     ))
    }     
   );
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a conflict between the return tuple of useState and the first variable in your array.

Something like this is the normal way to do this:

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(product.quantity);

const incrementCount = () => {
  setCount(prevCount => prevCount + 1);
};

const product = {
  ...
  quantity: count
};
```